# Is there some other way to connect to SQL Server without using migration in .NET Core razor project?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, razor

I keep getting an error when I try to run the add-migration command in the package manager console:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Version=3.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (0x80131040)

Here is my startup.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using BookListRazor.Model;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace BookListRazor
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContextPool<ApplicationDbContext>(option => option.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the appsettings.json

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=(LocalDb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=BookListRazor;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
  },

    "Logging": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Information",
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
      }
    },
    "AllowedHosts": "*"
  }
```